# How to check if string is a comment?

Tags: regex, bash, awk

How do I check if string starts with '#' ?

```
#path /var/dumpfolder
```

I tried awk for

```
awk -F '' '{print $1}'
```

Is there any better way ?

Comment: How do you want to check it? Just view? Or do you want messages?

Comment: Is the string a file or a variable in bash or what?

Comment: I basically want to check if string is commented if so, I want to remove that comment '#' from string and keep it. Yes a message or storing string without the comment. 
@Pills : string is in a variable in bash ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still cannot understand what are you trying to do, but there is [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) in your tags, so here is a bash solution to `check if string starts with '#'`

```
string='#path /var/dumpfolder'
```

```
if [[ $string == \#* ]]; then
    echo 'yes'
else
    echo 'no'
fi
```

or:

```
if [[ ${string:0:1} == '#' ]]; then
    echo 'yes'
else
    echo 'no'
fi
```

If you want to remove `#` character then use:

```
echo "${string#\#}" # prints 'path /var/dumpfolder'
```

This will remove `#` character if it exists. If it doesn't exist then the string will be left intact.

#### Edit:

If sometimes there are leading spaces, then use regexp:

```
if [[ $string =~ ^[[:space:]]*\#.*$ ]]; then
    echo "${string#*\#}"
else
    echo "$string"
fi
```

Comment: what if there is a space in front of the comment?

Answer (score 2):

```
^\s*[#](.*)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/PwmBtVbTtZeMqaB8)

here is a regular expression ..... if that's what you are looking for.

- `^` denotes the start of the string
- `\s*` means a one more spaces to take care of the case where there could be a space in front of the #
- `[#]` or just `#` works this checks that the first letter is a #
- `(.*)` grabs all(most) of the characters and throws them into a capture group
- `$` stops at the end of the string

This should work to remove the #'s in your code and spaces in front of the comment

```
sed 's/\^\s*[#](.*)$/\1/'
```

Comment: I just need to check if commented if so remove comment and extract rest of string. The regex gives me complete string with even '#' included and I want only rest of string

Comment: Why ``#`` in ``[]`` ? Seems like there's no need. Also why ``.*`` is in ``( )`` ? ``^\s#.*$`` should work as well.

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko For clarification you're right! I could leave it out. Also about the .*, I like putting stuff I want to match into capture groups just In case later i want to use them for something other than matching.(putting the values into an array)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to find `#path` or `path` (without #) pattern in file, do:

```
grep -E '^#?path' file
```

To just find `#path` exactly, don't add `?`:

```
grep -E '^#path' file
```

More exlicit is to add a space, but your separator could be a tab as well:

```
grep -E '^#path ' file
```

Answer (score 1):

> I basically want to check if string is commented if so, I want to
>   remove that comment '#' from string and keep it. Yes a message or
>   storing string without the comment.

so

```
sed 's/^\s*#*//'
```

example (with file):

```
kent$  cat f
#c1
 #c2
foo
bar

kent$  sed 's/^\s*#*//' f
c1
c2
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk '{sub(/^#/,"")}1' file
```